# Sails.js: Subscribing a User to specific actions on a Request

Tags: node.js, socket.io, messaging, sails.js, publish-subscribe

In my Sails project, I have a `User` model/controller and a `Request` model/controller, as well as a `Dashboard` controller. A user can make a request for data using `RequestController.create`, and an administrator can approve it using `RequestController.grant`.

What I want to do is to notify a user whenever one of his/her requests is approved (updated). In `RequestController.grant`, I call `Request.publishUpdate(...)`, and in my `DashboardController.display`, I call

```
Request.find(req.session.user.id, function(err, requests) { 
    ... 
    Request.subscribe(req, requests, ['update']) 
    ... 
});
```

Then, in the view `/dashboard/display`, I put in `<script>` tags:

```
<script>
// Socket handling for notifications
io.socket.on("request", function(obj) {
    alert(obj.verb);
    alert(obj.data);
    alert(obj.previous);
});
</script>
```

However, upon approving a user's request and going to the dashboard, no alerts show up. The script for sails.io is already loaded, with no errors in the console. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely problem here is that you're using `Request.subscribe` in an HTTP call.  I'm assuming that's the case since it seems like you're problem using `DashboardController.display` to display a view.  In this case, the `Request.subscribe` doesn't do anything at all (it should really display a warning) because it can't possibly know which socket to subscribe!

If you'd like to keep your controller logic the same (you might be using the `requests` array as a view local to bootstrap some data on the page), that's fine; a quick refactor would be to test whether or not its a socket call in the action:

```
// Also note the criteria for the `find` query below--just sending an
// ID won't work for .find()!
Request.find({user: req.session.user.id}, function(err, requests) { 
    ... 
    // If it's a socket request, subscribe and return success
    if (req.isSocket) {
        Request.subscribe(req, requests, ['update']) 
        return res.send(200);
    } 
    // Otherwise continue on displaying the view
    else {
        ... 
        return res.view('dashboard', {requests: requests});
    }
});
```

Then somewhere in your view call `io.socket.get('/dashboard/display')` to subscribe to `request` instances.

You could also use blueprints to subscribe to the requests from the front end, doing something like `io.socket.get('/request?user='+userId)`, if you put the user ID in the locals and add it somewhere in your view template, e.g. `<script>var userId=<%=user.id%></script>`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I took out the subscribe and just made a io.socket.get() call on the client side. However, I realize now that this isn't the behavior that I'm trying to achieve. If I open the admin panel in a new page and approve an instance of the Request model, the first page creates the alert just fine. But what if the user isn't logged in at that time - I still want to be able to show the notification when the user logs in. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: That's a totally separate problem--realtime messaging vs. queued notifications.  For the latter, I'd suggest starting with a simple `Notification` model to hold on to messages that can't be delivered in realtime.  Or do it Facebook-style, where you always save the notification, and use realtime to just update a badge indicating the # of notifications the user has, which are only cleared once they click to reveal all the messages.